# Close file before moving onto the next file

Tags: vba, excel

This macro loops through all the files in a directory and formats the data as a table.

I need to sort Column J on the table from Largest to Smallest and then save the file before moving onto the next file. Currently it leaves all the files open.

```vb
Sub LoopThroughFiles()

FolderName = "C:\Folder1\"
If Right(FolderName, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then FolderName = FolderName & Application.PathSeparator
Fname = Dir(FolderName & "*.xls")

'loop through the files
Do While Len(Fname)
  With Workbooks.Open(FolderName & Fname)
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes)
    tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"
    Columns("A:L").Select
    Columns("A:L").EntireColumn.AutoFit
  End With

  'go to the next file in the folder
  Fname = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the  line where you `Close` the workbook : `WB.Close True`.

(if you don't want to save the changes made to the workbook use `WB.Close False`)

**Note**: you are not setting the `Worksheet` object on the workbook you open, so by default it will assume the `ActiveSheet`, which is the last `ActiveSheet` the last time you saved this workbook.

Try the code below:

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()

Dim WB As Workbook

FolderName = "C:\Folder1\"
If Right(FolderName, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then FolderName = FolderName & Application.PathSeparator
fname = Dir(FolderName & "*.xls")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'loop through the files
Do While Len(fname)
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(FolderName & fname) '<-- set the workbook object
    With WB
        Dim tbl As ListObject
        Dim rng As Range

        Set rng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
        Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes)
        tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"
        Columns("A:L").Select
        Columns("A:L").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    WB.Close True ' <-- close workbook and save changes
    ' go to the next file in the folder
    fname = Dir
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Forgot to mention one thing... The compatibility checker pops up, is there a way around that?

Comment: Works good, what about the sorting from largest to smallest in column J? The worksheet names are different in each file, but the column is labeled as sales in each one, I'm still having trouble with the different sheet names.

Comment: @BrianFischer - Try to stick to one issue per question - it helps make SO a site that is useful for people who have similar issues in the future.  (Lots of people will have an issue where they need to work out how to save / close their workbook.  Lots of people will have an issue where they need to locate a column based on the header.  Very, very few will have an issue where they need to save/close the workbook AND locate a column based on the header.)

Comment: @YowE3K Will do! Thank you for the info!